# Foreach PHP Loop optimization?

Tags: php, mysql

I've below code

```
<?php
while($result=$stmt->fetch())
{
$lookup[] = $result['phost'];
}
foreach ($lookup as $host) {
echo '<tr><td>' . $host . '</td><td>' . $reverse_ip . '.' . $host . '</td>';
  if (@checkdnsrr($reverse_ip . "." . $host . ".", "A")) {
       echo '<td><span class="badge bg-red">Listed</span></td></tr>';
  } 
  else {
       echo '<td><span class="badge bg-yellow">Not Listed</span></td></tr>';
  }
}
?>
```

I've around 60+ records in table of column(phost) which i'm getting from SQL Query and saving all results in an array $lookup but my problem is, after submitting the form, it took so much time to load and i want to show the result one by one in table row with some nicely progress bar.

Please Help!

Comment: PHP output doesn't return to the client until the code is done. You won't be able to show a progress bar unless you return an empty table from PHP, then use Javascript to load the data and populate the rows of the table using websockets. That's pretty advanced. You'll be better off learning how to optimize your SQL and PHP code. Querying 60 records should be quick, so I guess you probably need to optimize the SQL query by creating an index. But you don't show the query.

Comment: Even i also want to save the above output in a table and want to create a unique URL as output of this scan /result123 , its bit hard for me !

Comment: The slowest part of this is going to be checkdnsrr, not the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

> The idea below is to preemptively check "hosts" so that users won't
> have to wait so long for results (skip this part if you don't care):
> Use cron job. Save results to database. Show results from database
> with date of last time record was checked and the page will load in
> milliseconds. You can add an option to send an email to the user when
> returning "Not Listed".

---

> If you want to give the user the ability to load or refresh the
> results with a nice progress bar you'll need more then just php since
> php is strictly used for back-end. You'll need to use JavaScript or
> JavaScript library such as jQuery. With jQuery you'll have the ability
> to send ajax request for each "host" and then display the response in
> a table.

---

> For more details and resources visit the links below:
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
>
> http://api.jquery.com/html/
>
> https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Can you share some nice tutorials regarding this?

Comment: A cronjob only runs once per minute as the smallest interval,  I'm not sure the solution to a slow HTTP response is to delay it from starting for up to a minute.

Comment: I did.  How are you going to start getting results before 1 minute if it's dispatched to a cronjob?

Comment: @Devon "if you want to give the user the ability to refresh the results with a nice progress..." seding an ajax request to a page with this code  if (@checkdnsrr($reverse_ip . "." . $host . ".", "A")) {
       echo '<td><span class="badge bg-red">Listed</span></td></tr>';
  } 
  else {
       echo '<td><span class="badge bg-yellow">Not Listed</span></td></tr>';
  }

Comment: I edited it to make it more clear that they are separate ideas.

Comment: @Devon If you have a better way of doing it please let us know we love learning here, if not please mark as helpful, Thank you!

Comment: @Tom, I'd upvote your second idea if you had more details about using AJAX or why you'd need to use JQuery since JQuery isn't tagged/involved in the question but as of right now, it looks more like a comment/suggestion rather than an answer.

Comment: @ChetanSoni give it a try, if you get stuck show us the progress of your code and we'll be here to help.